# parent and MovieClip(root) trouble

Tags: actionscript-3

Hello I have a problem with, as the title.

In my some class when I call parent. or MovieClip(root). in constructor, trace return error NULL but if I call mentioned up appeals in other private or public function (for instance, function from `addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, func);` it works, why ?

Can someone please explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't clearly understand your question, but if you would **call**:

> this.parent or
>   this.root

**in** your **constructor** method, it **will always be null** because ([from Adobe ref](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html)):

- > root

  property is the top-most display object in the portion of the display list's tree structure represented by that SWF file
- > parent

  property indicates the DisplayObjectContainer object that contains this display object

Your DisplayObject can not be added anywhere before it gets constructed. 
First you call

> var myDisplayObject:DisplayObject = new MyDisplayObject();

and then you add it to another DisplayObject or Stage (DisplayObjectContainer)

> anotherDisplayObject.addChild(myDisplayObject); /* now you have myDisplayObject parent and root property defined */

---

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class Picture extends Sprite
{
    public function Picture() 
    {
        trace(parent) // parent is null
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED, onAdded)
    }

    private function onAdded(e:Event):void 
    {
        trace(parent) // returns parent
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I have done so, var customScroll:DisplayObject = new CustomScroll(); and next stage.addChild(customScroll) in sequence call trace(this.parent.x) located in constructor and hereinafter return null :(

Comment: When i now use addEventListener(Event.ADDED, onAdded) without var myDisplayObject:DisplayObject = new MyDisplayObject(); etc. Work, but you cannot do without it calling in constructor ?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned before, .parent and .root properties in constructor are always null.